# How to access a method declared in a child class inside other a child class?

Tags: php

Im wondering if it's posible to access a method declared inside a child class inside other child class, and if so then how can i do that, and is that okay or it's consider to be a bad practice?

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {
  public function hello() {
    echo 'Hello World!';
  }
}
class C extends A {
  $this->hello();
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. If the object is a `C`, it's not a `B`, so it doesn't have the `hello()` method.

Comment: Depending on the scenario, you might be able to have `class C extends B` instead, or put the `hello` function into `class A2 extends A` and then extend A2 for both B and C, or refactor a little more aggressively to move `hello` into a trait that both B and C can use. Many ways to get to the sort of code sharing you're looking for.